# Add styles to title attribute

Tags: css, asp.net, webforms, font-awesome

I'm working on a ASP.Net Web Forms project .I need to show icon in Gridview row dynamically based on a condition and need to show a tool tip when user hovers on that icon. Using the title attribute I was able to show the tool tip, but I need to design the tool tip as required (Square). How can I achieve that ..? ,How to add style to **title** attribute ..?

This is the code behind method

```
 protected string GetUnsupportedIcon(MNDto a)
    {
        if (!a.Supported)
        {
            return $@"<i class=""fa fa-warning"" title='{message}'  style=""color:#EEA42E;font-size:16px""></i>";
        }
        else return $@"<i class=""hidden""></i>";
    }
```

Calling this method from aspx page

```
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:ColumnNewCategory.HeaderText %>" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" ItemStyle-CssClass="mxcell" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Outside">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%# ((MNDto)Container.DataItem).SuggestedCategory %>    <%# GetUnsupportedIcon((MNDto)Container.DataItem) %>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't style an actual title attribute**

How the text in the title attribute is displayed is defined by the browser and varies from browser to browser. It's not possible for a webpage to apply any style to the tooltip that the browser displays based on the title attribute.

**You can make a pseudo-tooltip with CSS and a custom attribute (e.g. data-title)**

Example code:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" title="Hello Stackoverflow!">
  Example code --- Hover me
</a>
```

Example CSS:

```
a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

a[title]:hover::after {
  content: attr(title);
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%;
  left: 0;
}
```